# Configuring TinyMCE in Magento 1.8

Tags: backend, entities, tinymce

TinyMCE has an very unfriendly feature for me: it escapes all accents to html entities once you switch from raw to visual and then to raw again.

I found the key that must be configured, now I would like to know the place to put the configuration for the backend editor to STOP escaping accents.

Anyone ? Thanks.

Comment: The problem with Magento 1.8.1.0 and Tiny Mce is that all changes to
*/js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js
are not giving visible effect. Any hints where real config is placed or where to find those setup files that override standard setup.js in TinyMCE. THX

Comment: The comment of @EvgeniIvanov is correct, it worked fine here 1.8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this file *magento_installation_directory*/js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js, on line 97(Magento 1.7.0.2 CE) you will find a variable named settings. You need to add this option: entity_encoding : "raw". You can read more about it here tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:entity_encoding. Please note that if you upgrade Magento, you may need to apply this again.

Comment: Well, tough luck for us non English speakers. This does work, but it breaks if you enable "Merge JavaScript Files". Apparently the 'js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js' is loaded after the merged files.

I'm working on a solution.Till then as a workarounf disabling JS merging globally and enable it on any Website you have.

Answer (score 1):

The configuraion file for TinyMCE is located here:
*magento_installation_directory*/js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js

You can edit/add your settings to this file.

Comment: It would be stellar if you could update your answer to include context and example surrounding what's being asked vs merely posting a file-path.

Comment: in this file *magento_installation_directory*/js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js, on line 97(Magento 1.7.0.2 CE) you will find a variable named settings. You need to add this option: entity_encoding : "raw". You can read more about it here http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:entity_encoding. Please note that if you upgrade Magento, you may need to apply this again. Best regards.

Comment: Thanks @EvgeniIvanov, please add an answer with your solution so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Also try changing the encoding of file setup.js to utf8 using a text editor. I had problem with greek characters and i did this after adding entity_encoding : "raw"